# Is this example a violation of star schema?

Tags: database, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I'm building a simple star schema in data warehouse with two dimensions based off of business entities: `dim_loan` and `dim_borrower`. There are also some fact tables, such as `fact_loan_status` which has one row per month for each loan showing the balance at that time, and has an FK back to `dim_loan`.

So here's my question: if `dim_loan` has a FK for `borrower_id` back to `dim_borrower`, does that violate star schema? Nearly all discussion of the star schema revolves around individual dim tables that only have FK relations with fact tables, not fellow dims. Making a fact_loan_borrower doesn't make sense to me for this simple one-to-one relationship.

Any advice would be welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

if dim_borrower and dim_loan have the same cardinality, then keeping both ids (loan_id, borrower_id) in the fact_loan_borrower would help you gain performance. You need only one join to bring borrower or loan information from respective dimensions. If you keep borrower_id as FK in dim_loan you need to use two joins if you need to bring borrowers information.

If the two dimensions have different cardinality then it is wise to attach dimension with low cardinality with the fact table - it will help to keep fact table small.

The choice of star and snowflake schema fully depends on you.